# Magento Multiwebsite With Single Database & Single Admin

Tags: magento

Friends

Can i create **multiple web store** with **single admin and database** **in Magento**. i want to host these stores from different servers. In other words my database and code (different code for different site) would be on different servers.

**for ex:** i have **abc.com** and **xyz.com** stores created in Magento hosted on different servers but the database is same.

i have already created **multi-store concept** in Magento with **Magento's default functionality** but in that case we can't host different website from different server because there is a single code for both of the site or store

why i wanted to use this concept just because of security purpose and in case of server crash there will be no harm to other web store because they are hosted from different servers

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen such scheme before but I don't think this will work.

From the implementation's view, it requires a dedicated empty database in which the tables will be created as part of the installation process. So when you install a second Magento on the same database, all tables written by the previous Magento installation shall be erased.